# Why isn't my React app deploying on GitHub

Tags: reactjs, github

I'm trying to publish a react app I build on VS code, but it's not working. I followed this tutorial (https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) but I can't access it at the address, I get 404. Here's my repo I'm trying use https://github.com/LazaroFilm/markdown-previewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. I needed to set the default branch in my GitHub repo settings.
[image: GitHub Pages setting]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean getting 404 on Github Pages, then be a little patient since it takes some time for github pages to show your demo